# React-Native [Unable to re-render ListView after changes in data]

Tags: listview, react-native

I have been to all the blogs and post where user had asked almost similar question what I am about to ask, but problem with me is little different I had followed all the possible solutions mentioned on previous questions.

**Issue: I am using list-view where I am rendering some data and I want to update data on click. I am able to make changes in list but those changes are not reflecting back to list-View.**

I have used url to fetch list and set data on list view. and when I try to make changes in old list from state it doesn't reflect back.
my code:

```
rowData.adult = !rowData.adult;
    var dataClone = this.state.familyData;
    dataClone[rowID] = rowData;
    this.setState(state => ({
      familyData: this.state.familyData.cloneWithRows(dataClone),
    }));
```

If I re-hit URL and then try to update it will append changes in list-view.
Code for this:

```
 Presscall(rowID) {
    var url = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=17e62b78e65bd6b35f038505c1eec409';
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(jsonData => {
        console.log("data", jsonData.results[rowID].adult);
        jsonData.results[rowID].adult = true;
        var dataclone = jsonData.results;
        this.setState({
          familyData: this.state.familyData.cloneWithRows(dataclone),
          fetching: false`enter code here`
        });
        console.log("data", jsonData.results[rowID].adult);
      })
      .catch(error => console.log('Error fetching: ' + error));
  }
```

**Please help me out with this, Thanks in advance.**

Comment: where is Presscall defined ?

Comment: All the methods are defined inside class only.